# How can I stop code execution by sequentially pressing ctrl+c without calling KeyboardInterrupt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It is necessary that the first time <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> is pressed, a message is displayed, but the code does not stop working, and if after pressing <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> is pressed again within 2 seconds, then the execution of the code is stopped, while the program runs indefinitely.

```
import keyboard
import time

def waiting():
    curtime = time.perf_counter()
    while (time.perf_counter() - curtime) <= 2:
        keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + v', exit())
    cycle()

def cycle():
    while True:
        try:
            keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + c', lambda: print('Hello'))
        except KeyboardInterrupt():
            waiting()

cycle()
```

Comment: Why "without calling KeyboardInterrupt"?

Comment: I don't understand "the execution of the code is stopped, while the program runs indefinitely" – how can it be stopped while running indefinitely at the same time?

Comment: The main infinite loop is started. Ctrl +c is expected to be pressed. After that, the user is given 2 seconds. If he presses ctrl + c again at this time, the program ends. If not, the infinite loop resumes

Comment: i mean that Keyboard Interrypt must be call later.

Comment: not at first time

Comment: maybe the keyboard.add_hotkey() should have "ctrl + c"

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below piece of code. I think it solves the purpose.

```py
    import keyboard
    import time
    
    def cycle():
        start  = -3.0
        while True:
          if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+c'):
            if time.perf_counter() - start <= 2:
                break
            print('Hello')  # write your code here
            start = time.perf_counter()
            time.sleep(.15)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        cycle()
```

edit 1: [explanation]
initially we are setting the `start` to any random float value less than than `-2`. So that our *2 second time check* fails for the very first time.

Now our `while` loop will continue forever without printing anything until `ctrl+c` is pressed.

When you press `ctrl+c` the very first time, `if time.perf_counter() - start <= 2:` will fail as we have set the `start = -3.0` initially. A message `Hello` is printed and `start` is updated with the updated time and out loop continues to run.
Here `time.sleep` is required as we have `while True` and not performing any work except two if checks. so we need to add some delay.

Now when you press `ctrl+c` again if `time.perf_counter() - start <= 2` is **true** then your loop will break and nothing will be printed and if `time.perf_counter() - start <= 2` is **false** then message is printed and `start` is updated again.

Comment: it doesnt work as i wanted because when i press ctrl + c code mustnt stop, it must continue to work while ctrl + c wont pressed again for 2 seconds, need to stop call KeyboardInterrupt when it work first time. Please read comments up, i tried explane how it does work

Comment: instead ctrl +v - ctrl + c  i missed but it not important

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Write a program that does not perform any visible
actions after launch, but does not terminate either; when pressed, ^C prints a message; when pressed
^With twice with an interval of less than 2 seconds - shuts down.

Comment: code must satisfy the condition of the problem written above

Comment: @The_BESToloch I have added the explanation of the code I've written. Let me know if i misunderstood anything. This code will only break if you press ctrl+c twice within 2 seconds.

Comment: there are no problems in the logic, but an exception is still called

Comment: Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EGOR\Desktop\mai\IT\зачёт\15.py", line 50, in <module>
    cycle()
  File "C:\Users\EGOR\Desktop\mai\IT\зачёт\15.py", line 47, in cycle
    time.sleep(.15)
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: its called after first ctrl c

Comment: I think this is due to a feature of the language or interpreter. I managed to do something with the help of signals.

Comment: def globalTime():
    while True:
        timing = time.time()
        yield timing
firtstThread = threading.Thread(target=globalTime)
firtstThread.start()
firtstThread.join()

def cycle(Array):
    for i in range(1, len(Array)):
        if Array[i]-Array[i-1] <2:
            exit()
def callback(type, frame):
    global flag, Array
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+c') or flag==True:
        for thetime in globalTime():
            flag = False
            Array.append(thetime)
            cycle(Array)
            break
while True:
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, callback)

Comment: i done it, but i cant share herej.

Comment: if some one interested

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/1078492?e=12008046#answer_item_2061458

Comment: thats link on my code